# Replace listeners with RxJava

Tags: android, reactive-programming, rx-java, observable, rx-android

Currently I am investigating a migration to RxJava and decided that  a manager of mine(accountManager) would be an interesting place to start. Currently the Manager has a list of listeners and sends updates accordingly, both when the account gets updated and when something goes wrong.

```
private List<WeakReference<ProfileChangeListener>> mListeners = new ArrayList<>();

public interface ProfileChangeListener {
    void onProfileUpdated(Account account);
    void onProfileFailed(Exception e);
}
```

My Rx solution involves a `Subject`

```
private SerializedSubject<Account, Account> mManagerSubject = new SerializedSubject<>(BehaviorSubject.<Account>create());

public Observable<Account> observe() {
    return mManagerSubject;
}
```

and then when an update happens I call one of the following:

```
private void onProfileUpdated(Account account) {
    mManagerSubject.onNext(account);
}

private void onProfileFailed(final Exception e) {
    mManagerSubject.onError(e);
}
```

**Issue**

The Issue is that once `onError` is called anyone listening via `observe` will never get another update from `onNext`.

I still want the subscribers to receive onError so they can handle the error state but at a later time `onNext` could still be called with an updated account and I still want the subscribers to handle the updated account.

I've tried solutions using `onErrorResumeNext`, `onErrorReturn` `onExceptionResumeNext` but none of them propagate the `onError`.

*TLDR:* How do I keep the subscribers subscribed after onError is called while still propagating onError?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Errors" in Rx can be a a little difficult to grasp at first, because they have a slightly different meaning from what most people expect.

From the [Error Handling documentation](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Error-Handling) (emphasis mine):

> An Observable typically does not throw exceptions. Instead it notifies any observers that **an unrecoverable error has occurred** by terminating the Observable sequence with an onError notification.

`onError()` is supposed to be used when an `Observable` encounters an *unrecoverable* error- that is when your `Observable` cannot continue emitting items. When you are subscribing, you might use something like `onErrorResumeNext` to try some recovery action, but that should be the end of the source `Observable`.

Instead, you may want to adjust what your `Observable` emits to support emitting an error item, or include a flag indicating that an error was encountered.

If your error truly is unrecoverable, then you may want to revisit your recovery strategy and try a slightly different approach.